# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 6790, 6771

Tags: r, xts

I have followed the instructions to calculate the [log returns of multiple securities for multiple time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514240/log-returns-of-multiple-securities-for-multiple-time-period-in-r) and it works fine for computing daily returns of my data set. Now my problem begins when I calculate the monthly returns as of the latest date. Using the formula to get the monthly return:

```
logs=data.frame(
     cbind.data.frame(
         prices$Date[-1],
         na.locf(diff(as.matrix(log(prices[,-1])), lag = 20))
         )
     )
```

I'm getting:

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply
>   differing number of rows: 6790, 6771

Understandably, the difference in row number is coming from the 20-day lag I used to get the monthly return as of date. I also need to compute annual returns as of date and I think I am also going to get the same error when I do so. I tried using `merge.data.frame` instead of `cbind.data.frame` but only led to my computer crashing.

I took the first 10 rows and columns of my dataset:

```
        Date `2GO`   AAA    AB   ABA   ABG   ABS    AC   ACE   ACR
       <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  28-Jun-17 23.25  1.61 14.98  0.37 28.25 42.85 841.5  1.61  1.50
2  27-Jun-17 23.90  1.61 14.98  0.37 27.95 42.90 842.5  1.61  1.53
3  23-Jun-17 24.60  1.61 14.98  0.38 27.00 42.90 840.5  1.70  1.57
4  22-Jun-17 24.40  1.61 14.98  0.37 28.05 43.20 855.0  1.67  1.57
5  21-Jun-17 24.80  1.61 15.00  0.37 28.05 43.10 841.5  1.67  1.57
6  20-Jun-17 25.10  1.61 14.68  0.37 28.85 43.45 858.0  1.70  1.58
7  19-Jun-17 24.85  1.61 14.68  0.37 29.05 43.40 860.0  1.75  1.55
8  16-Jun-17 25.70  1.61 14.68  0.38 29.60 43.45 850.0  1.77  1.52
9  15-Jun-17 26.20  1.61 14.48  0.38 29.55 43.30 867.0  1.69  1.53
10 14-Jun-17 26.85  1.61 16.00  0.37 29.50 43.35 867.5  1.69  1.52
```

Using the code Florian provided and used 3 as lag:

```
logs=data.frame(
  cbind.data.frame(
    p$Date[-1],
    c(rep(NA,3), na.locf(diff(as.matrix(log(p[,-1])), lag = 3)))
  )
)
```

still puts out an error:

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply
>   differing number of rows: 9, 66

Is there a way to remedy the error / fix the row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edited based on updated question.

Since the lag for 20 periods does exist not in the initial periods, you might pad with NA's. The problem is that `prices$Date[-1]` has a different number of rows than `na.locf(diff(as.matrix(log(prices[,-1])), lag = 20))`. You should make sure that they number of rows is equal. For example like this:

```
p = read.table(text="Date `2GO`   AAA    AB   ABA   ABG   ABS    AC   ACE   ACR
28-Jun-17 23.25  1.61 14.98  0.37 28.25 42.85 841.5  1.61  1.50
27-Jun-17 23.90  1.61 14.98  0.37 27.95 42.90 842.5  1.61  1.53
23-Jun-17 24.60  1.61 14.98  0.38 27.00 42.90 840.5  1.70  1.57
22-Jun-17 24.40  1.61 14.98  0.37 28.05 43.20 855.0  1.67  1.57
21-Jun-17 24.80  1.61 15.00  0.37 28.05 43.10 841.5  1.67  1.57
20-Jun-17 25.10  1.61 14.68  0.37 28.85 43.45 858.0  1.70  1.58
19-Jun-17 24.85  1.61 14.68  0.37 29.05 43.40 860.0  1.75  1.55
16-Jun-17 25.70  1.61 14.68  0.38 29.60 43.45 850.0  1.77  1.52
15-Jun-17 26.20  1.61 14.48  0.38 29.55 43.30 867.0  1.69  1.53
14-Jun-17 26.85  1.61 16.00  0.37 29.50 43.35 867.5  1.69  1.52",header=T)

p=p[order(p$Date),]

logs=data.frame(
  cbind.data.frame(
    Date = p$Date[4:nrow(p)],
    na.locf(diff(as.matrix(log(p[,-1])), lag = 3))
  )
)
```

Output:

```
       Date      X.2GO. AAA           AB         ABA          ABG          ABS
7 19-Jun-17 -0.07740807   0 -0.086102699  0.00000000 -0.015371780  0.001152738
6 20-Jun-17 -0.04289156   0  0.013717636 -0.02666825 -0.023973751  0.003458217
5 21-Jun-17 -0.03564734   0  0.021564178 -0.02666825 -0.053785729 -0.008087855
4 22-Jun-17 -0.01827462   0  0.020229955  0.00000000 -0.035029851 -0.004618946
3 23-Jun-17 -0.02012140   0  0.020229955  0.02666825 -0.066273127 -0.012739026
2 27-Jun-17 -0.03696519   0 -0.001334223  0.00000000 -0.003571432 -0.004651171
1 28-Jun-17 -0.04827800   0  0.000000000  0.00000000  0.007104826 -0.008134850
            AC          ACE          ACR
7 -0.008683123  0.034887259  0.019544596
6 -0.010434877  0.005899722  0.032157112
5 -0.010050336 -0.058155920  0.032365285
4 -0.005830920 -0.046792162  0.012820688
3 -0.020607147  0.000000000 -0.006349228
2  0.001187649 -0.036589447 -0.025807884
1 -0.015915455 -0.036589447 -0.045610511
```

Don't forget to check if the output is as expected. I am just showing you why the code is not working and a way of matching the number of rows within the statement, I am not familiar with the operation you are performing. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Florian, thank you for helping me out on this one. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error using the formula you posted above, only with different numbers from 6790, 6771 to 6790, 1855547. I tested your first code and it works, but I don't know why the second one won't.

Comment: Is there a way to make a small example e.g. take the first ten rows of your dataset and use a lag of 3? Then paste the data you use in your question, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example That makes it easier to help you out.

Comment: Hi @Florian, apologies for not posting a sample. I included the first 10 rows and columns of my dataset in my original post and used 3 as lag for the formula you provided.

Comment: Thanks @Florian! This is very helpful. Just to make sure that I completely understand the updated formula, the 4 in Date = p$Date[4:nrow(p)] corresponds to lag + 1, correct?

Comment: Yes, the first 3 rows of the p$Date column are skipped in doing so. I believe you should order you p dataframe descending on your date column first by the way, to perform the operation you want to perform. I updated the example. Could you please accept my answer if this works for you? Thanks!